# Calculator with one textfield

Tags: java, calculator

I want to make a calculator with a single text field, can you help?

For Example , i will add "2+2*5" and it will give the result.

i want to make it using Java , i wrote a code but i dont know how to make it work

```
public class Calculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner my_scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    String[] splitArray = null ;
    String[] stringArray = null ;
    String regex = "[0-9]+";
    String opr;
    int [] Cast = null;
    String number;
    int Answer;


    System.out.println("Enter your equation");

    input = my_scanner.nextLine();
    splitArray = input.split("\\s+");

    for(int i=0;i<splitArray.length;i++){

        if(splitArray.toString().matches(regex)){

        stringArray[i] = Character.toString(splitArray.toString().charAt(i));


    } else {

        opr = Character.toString(splitArray.toString().charAt(i));
        number = stringArray[i].toString();
        Cast[i] = Integer.parseInt(number);

        if(Cast.length == 2){
            Arrays.fill( Cast, (Integer) null );
        }


        switch(opr){

        case "+":
            Answer = Cast[1] + Cast[2];


        }

    }




}

}
```

}

Comment: What is the specific problem with your code?

Comment: @SteveSmith first i add plus operator but then i will add other operators , it run but it cant make summation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, example enter: 2+2, you call the split array function, but the returned value is string itself with length 1(not characters)=("2+2").convert to character array.

```
String[] result = input.toCharArray();
```

Then you can now loop per index. `int len = result.length;` eg, 0=2,1=+,2=2
Make sense?

Comment: use intellij to debug, there are few notefull errors.

Comment: also where did you initialize the Cast variable, such is a example of error. null pointer exception 100%